# What are RF waves referenced too?

Tags: rf, radio

Suppose I have a transmitter and a receiver circuit.

The transmitter circuit is powered by a battery and the receive circuit is powered by another battery. Both circuits are separated by 10m (for example).

My question is:

1. When the transmitter circuit (suppose it is transmitting at 433MHz) transmits a signal through the air, what is this signal referenced to?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'referenced to'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott before it leaves the transmitter pcb that signal will be referenced to (what is it "ground") the transmitter pcb ground. Is it still referenced to the transmitter pcb ground when it travels through air?

Comment: An EM wave doesn't require an electrical circuit to help it propagate @JoeyB

Answer (score 3):

Electromagnetic waves do not require a reference conductor in order to propagate.

For example, light from the sun is an electromagnetic wave and it is able to propagate to the Earth very well with nothing but vacuum between the Sun and Earth.

Similarly, a radio transmitter can send electromagnetic waves to your receiver without any reference conductor, and without the need for a return current or signal of any kind to flow from the receiver to the trasmitter. Radio communications can also be used between satellites in space without any material at all between the transmitter and receiver.